# context.xml for retrieve resources on disc issue Tomcat/Java EE

Tags: java, tomcat, context.xml

I'm trying to get some pics from disc I had put the pic as

```
D:
|
|-images
       |
       |-attachments
                ->testimg.jpg
```

and I'm trying to get this pics using a context file in META-INF on the webapp
here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context  docBase="D:\images\attachments" path="/Projet/attachments/" reloadable="true" crossContext="true" />
```

in the Java code to set the img src attribut I do

```
pics.setSrc("/attachments/testimg.jpg");
```

but the problem is when I run the page in the browser motion that the ressource isn't found and when I inspect the network I found the type is text/html 
 [image]
[image]
I hope you could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the forward slash from the end of your path. So modify `path="/Projet/attachments/"` to `path="/Projet/attachments"` I've replicated it locally and it solved the problem.

The reason why you get text/html type back when trying to retrieve a resource that doesn't exist is because the webserver (in our case tomcat) generates a 404 error page, and that is of type text/html. Just try manually hitting `http://localhost:8080/path/that/does/not/exist.jpg` you should get the same result.

---

Further info

If you want to set it up with a clean install, no Java code needed to test the mapping

- Deploy tomcat
- Edit conf/server.xml

```xml
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
   .
   .
   <Context  docBase="/space/images/attachments" path="/Projet/attachments" reloadable="true" />
</Host>
```

- (Re)start tomcat
- Hit `http://localhost:8080/Projet/attachments/testimg.jpg` in browser

Comment: I tested it ,it's not working ,I don't know if the context file is working or not ,where should I put this lines in the server.xml in eclipse or in conf/server.xml or in META-INF/context.xml of the webapp?

Comment: For testing it's easiest to change it in `conf/server.xml`. Put your `Context` node inside the `Host`. I'm saying it's easiest as there aren't any overriding rules so it definitely takes effect.